# Which is the best practice to write sql

Tags: sql

Below two queries give same results.
Just wanted to know which one is better in terms of performance.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT N.*
FROM   NOTIFICATIONS N
       JOIN NOTIFICATION_COMPANY_GROUPS NCG
          ON ( N.COMPANY_ID = NCG.COMPANY_ID
          AND N.ID = NCG.NOTIFICATION_ID )
       JOIN COMPANY_USER_GROUPS CUG
          ON ( N.COMPANY_ID = CUG.COMPANY_ID
          AND CUG.COMPANY_GROUP_ID = NCG.COMPANY_GROUP_ID )
       JOIN NOTIFICATION_PROPERTIES NP ON ( N.COMPANY_ID = NP.COMPANY_ID )
       JOIN COMPANY_USER_PROPERTIES CUP
          ON ( N.COMPANY_ID = CUP.COMPANY_ID
          AND CUP.PROPERTY_ID = NP.PROPERTY_ID )
WHERE  N.COMPANY_ID = 2138
AND    CUG.COMPANY_USER_ID = 41422
AND    CUP.COMPANY_USER_ID = 41422;
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT N.*
FROM   NOTIFICATIONS N
       JOIN NOTIFICATION_COMPANY_GROUPS NCG
          ON ( N.COMPANY_ID = 2138
          AND N.COMPANY_ID = NCG.COMPANY_ID
          AND N.ID = NCG.NOTIFICATION_ID )
       JOIN COMPANY_USER_GROUPS CUG
          ON ( CUG.COMPANY_USER_ID = 41422
          AND N.COMPANY_ID = CUG.COMPANY_ID
          AND CUG.COMPANY_GROUP_ID = NCG.COMPANY_GROUP_ID )
       JOIN NOTIFICATION_PROPERTIES NP ON ( N.COMPANY_ID = NP.COMPANY_ID )
       JOIN COMPANY_USER_PROPERTIES CUP
          ON ( CUP.COMPANY_USER_ID = 41422
          AND N.COMPANY_ID = CUP.COMPANY_ID
          AND CUP.PROPERTY_ID = NP.PROPERTY_ID );
```

Comment: The query planner should treat these two forms equivalently - view the query plan in the *particular* SQL implementation to see if there are any surprises. That being said, I recommend that all (and only) JOIN terms are in the `ON ..` bit, and everything else in the `WHERE`. That is, I recommend the first form - I find it simpler to read/understand and easier to generate, modify, or integrate into an outer query.

Comment: Why not measure it? For the rest: try to write your statements as easy to understand as possible (which is a bit a matter of taste/way of thinking). This will make it easier to get the statements semantically correct (and to maintain them). Only if you encounter performance problems, try alternatives. ("Premature optimization is the root of all evil", says D.E.Knuth)

Answer (score 7):

I expect the performance should be the same, but you can use `EXPLAIN` to verify that the query plan is the same.

However, the first version is the "proper" way to write it. Generally, `ON` clauses should only contain conditions that relate the tables being joines, while conditions on single tables should be in `WHERE` clauses.

**The only exception to this is in `LEFT JOIN` clauses**, where conditions on the table being joined should be in the `ON` clause.  This is because if you put them in the `WHERE` clause, the null rows from rows in the main table that have no matches in the joining table will be filtered out unless you explicitly check for `NULL`. As an example:

```
SELECT ...
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.T1_id = T1.id AND T2.someCol = 3
```

versus

```
SELECT ...
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.T1_id = T1.id
WHERE T2.someCol = 3
```

In the first version, the test of `T2.someCol` is done *before* joining; the result will contain all rows from `T1`, but the ones with no matching row in `T2` will have `NULL` for all the `T2` columns. But the second version won't have any of these non-matching rows, because the join is done first, and then it performs the `T2.someCol = 3` test; if there was no matching `T2` row, `T2.someCol` will be `NULL`, and this test will fail and the row will be filtered out by `WHERE`.

In the case of an inner join, it doesn't matter whether you do the comparison before or after joining, the results are equivalent. The query planner should order these in whichever way takes best advantage of indexes.

Comment: The part that says "The only exception" should be in bold face; it is very important and source of many bugs.

Comment: I don't get the part about the left join. Is that talking about simply moving the fixed-terms (e.g. `cup.company_user_id = 41422`) in that case? Or is that referring specifically to the joining conditions?

Comment: I've added an example for the left join.